# Start several Functions by chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got factory with some return on open modal window 
Example:

```
openModal: function (urn, id, templateId, controller) {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: urn
                }).success(function (data, $scope) {
                    $("#" + id).append($compile(data)($scope));
                    modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl: templateId,
                        controller: controller,
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    });
                }).error(function () {
                    alert("error");
                    return null;
                });
                document.getElementById('main').classList.add("blur");
            },
```

After this function and view append to DOM, I want to call another function 
 from another service witch i inject to thouse openModalfactory.

Example:

```
$map.autocomplite('wizardsearch');
$map.getAutoUserLocationPath();
```

Could you explain how I must do this through $q?
Thank you for you answer.

Comment: What do you mean by _"how I must do this through $q"_?

Comment: I'd like to use here angular $q methods. But if you know some another answer plz write it for me. I don't understand how $q must work. So I ask a help.

Comment: _"plz write it for me"_  <--- this is not an appropriate question.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: is the function you want to call async?

Comment: Yes I want to make async call function the second example in my question I want to call after my view from first example compiled and appended to DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deferring should make the function return a `promise` which you can use to do something when this function is finished
look to the the following code

```
openModal: function (urn, id, templateId, controller,$q) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: urn
            }).success(function (data, $scope) {
                def.resolve(data);
                $("#" + id).append($compile(data)($scope));
                modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: templateId,
                    controller: controller,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                });
            }).error(function (err) {
                def.reject(err)
                alert("error");

            });
            document.getElementById('main').classList.add("blur");
             return def.promise;
           }
```

to use it call it like :

```
openModel().then(function(){     
   //do what you want here
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand how it work. All work perfect.

Comment: glad to help you!

Comment: Peter could you help me more? All work good. But I need to use second function after I $compile and append my data to DOM. How I can make this? In case, callback from google API come faster then append Data in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you want something like this :

```
let deferred = this.$q.defer();
let promises = [];
promises.push(service.something);
this.$q.all(promises).then(/*Do something*/);
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Could you say me how to do this on my example?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do to your case, but this is an easy way to do what you want with $q

Comment: Could you make you example to my question , not only example what do you write on you answer. The reall example how to you this in my question.